Analytic uniformization
On page 3 of Moschovakis' Descriptive Set Theory, he mentions that Lusin and Sierpinski already knew (before Kondo) that Borel sets can be uniformized by $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$ sets, and that analytic sets can be uniformized by projective sets. Later Kondo showed $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_2$ uniformizations, so in particular analytic sets can be uniformized by $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_2$ sets.
Is this optimal? I have a simple "proof" that in fact analytic sets can be uniformized by coanalytic sets, but it's probably wrong, since otherwise Moschovakis should have stated that. Suppose $X$ is Polish, $A\subseteq X\times X$ is analytic and $f:\mathcal{N}\rightarrow X\times X$ is a continuous map with image $A$. Let $p:X\times X\rightarrow X$ be the projection onto the first coordinate. Define a partial map $g$ from $X$ to $\mathcal{N}$ by
$g(x)=a$ iff $p(f(a))=x\land \forall b\in\mathcal{N}[p(f(b))=x\rightarrow a\leq b]$
where $\leq$ is the lexicographical order on $\mathcal{N}$. In plain English, since $(p\circ f)^{-1}(x)$ is a closed subset of $\mathcal{N}$ it has a left-most branch, which we choose to be $g(x)$. Then the second coordinate of $f\circ g$ is the uniformizing function. The definition of $g$ seems like $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$. So what is the issue in the above proof?
Edit: I may have found the gap: $f\circ g$ may not be $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$ even though $g$ is? In that case, what was Lusin's
(presumably simple) argument for uniformizing Borel sets by $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$ sets?
